# Problem opening site with Nokogiri - Request timeout - Etags to blame?

Tags: ruby, curl, web-scraping, nokogiri, etag

I'm trying to open MrPorter.com using nokogiri

```
 Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.mrporter.com"))
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
Net::ReadTimeout: Net::ReadTimeout with #<TCPSocket:(closed)>
from /Users/8bithero/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:217:in `rbuf_fill'
```

This worked previously but they have since added etags which I'm not sure if it might be the culprit.

Is there any way around this? Is it still possible to open this page (or similar) using Nokogiri? Maybe I'm missing some required params?

---

There is an API call you can make using postman (and adding `content-type: application/json`)

```
https://www.mrporter.com/api/inseason/search/resources/store/mrp_gb/productview/666467151985458?locale=en_GB
```

But if you hit this directly it won't work unless you first visit the product page:
https://www.mrporter.com/en-gb/mens/product/red-wing-shoes/shoes/lace-up-boots/8138-moc-leather-boots/666467151985458

This seems to set etags with expiration time of about 5 minutes, this was what made me thing it might be the etags at fault.

Has any one got any ideas how to get either of them accessible?

Comment: etags shouldn't cause a timeout. Note that nokogiri isn't raising this error, the Net::HTTP library is. Try connecting to the server with just Net::HTTP and see if you can get the content that way through a different timeout configuration. There's more info for this exception on https://www.exceptionalcreatures.com/bestiary/Net/ReadTimeout.html.

Comment: The problem definitely isn't Nokogiri as it doesn't open anything, [it only reads something that is opened, or it parses a string](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/HTML/Document.html#parse-class_method), so I'm removing that tag. Please read "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)". We need the smallest piece of code that demonstrates the problem in the question itself you're asking us to write it which everyone will do differently.

Comment: You are getting this error after 60 seconds, eh?

Comment: `ETAGs` won't cause this problem, only their side not responding with the full payload in time. That can be caused by a broken server, a broken network anywhere between your machine and their host, a broken TCP/IP stack on your machine. You can debug using `wget` or `curl` and see if those work correctly.

Comment: Their site appears to be sniffing the user-agent information because it hangs with non-browsers. They could be doing so to stop scraping attempts, which are usually a violation of the TOS. How to work around that is left for your research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you send a net/http request, the site is protected for user-agent verification. You can parse the page as follows:

```
require 'nokogiri'

page = `curl --user-agent "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)" https://www.mrporter.com/en-gb/`
parse_page = Nokogiri::HTML(page)
```

You will get a parsed page

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I was hoping for! There is a slight typo, though. `Nokogiri::HTML(page)` is missing the second colon (Tried editing but it was less than 6 characters so didn't allow changes). Thanks again! :)

Comment: fixed nokogiri namespace )